# Regex - get group 1 as "full match"/group 0

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Given the following examples, I want to get the email address

```
Eg. 1: some standard text.   Bugs Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text 
Eg. 2: some standard text.   Bugs The Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text
Eg. 3: some standard text.   Bugs-Bunny bugs.bunny@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text
Eg. 4: some standard text.   Bugs bugs.bunny@gmail.com +6141 111 111 more standard text
Eg. 5: some standard text.   Bugs o'Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text
```

This will do it: `(?<=some standard text.   )(?:.*?)([^\s]+@[^\s]+)` https://regex101.com/r/A29hjE/9

But the email address is in group 1. I need it to be group 0 or the full match because this regex will be created dynamically by some code in which all other regex's produce their findings as the full match.

I don't know enough about groups, but I know I need the first email address after the `some standard text.` bit and, like I said, it need's to be the full match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your regex to simply be ([^\s]+@[^\s]+), the full result should be just the email address.

Comment: I get that, in the examples given, but I need the first email address after after `some standard text.` as there are email address in the full text.

Comment: Basically, you're asking to match for "some standard text", but then not display that in the full result. I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$lines = array(
"some standard text.   Bugs Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text ",
"some standard text.   Bugs The Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text",
"some standard text.   Bugs-Bunny bugs.bunny@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text",
"some standard text.   Bugs bugs.bunny@gmail.com +6141 111 111 more standard text",
"some standard text.   Bugs o'Bunny bugs@gmail.com 0411111111 more standard text ",
);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    preg_match('/some standard text..+?\K\S+@\S+/', $line, $m);
    var_dump($m);
}
```

where:

- `\K` means forget all we have encountered until here.
- `\S` stands for any NON whitespace, it's the same that `[^\s]`

Then we have only the email in `$m[0]`

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "bugs@gmail.com"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "bugs@gmail.com"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "bugs.bunny@gmail.com"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "bugs.bunny@gmail.com"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "bugs@gmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Group 0 **is** the full match.

If you change your regex to just be `[^\s]+@[^\s]+` then it will match the email address in all your examples. https://regex101.com/r/SQL9Ul/1

Because of the varying length of the name, you cannot use a positive lookbehind and match the email address as the whole match.